# Why binded TextBlock`s value can be not changed after the property to which it is bounded changed and event PropertyChanged invoked?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, desktop

I'm trying to create a bind between a TextBlock and a property at the ViewModel class which implements IPropertyChanged interface. Actually, my property changes, event invokes, but TextBlock`s value does not change.

**Here is my XAML code**

```
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                            Width="120"
                                            Text="{Binding SelectedMatch.Entries[0].CompetingTeam.TeamName, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource TeamNameConverter}}"/>

                                <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                                            Text="{Binding SelectedMatch.Entries[0].Score}"
                                            Width="50"
                                            FontFamily="Montserrat"/>
                            </Grid>
```

**View model**

```
    public class TournamentViewerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private MatchModel _selectedMatch;

        public MatchModel SelectedMatch
        {
            get => _selectedMatch;
            set
            {
                _selectedMatch = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(SelectedMatch, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedMatch)));
            }
        }
```

**Match model**

```
    public class MatchModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public List<MatchEntryModel> Entries { get; set; } = new List<MatchEntryModel>();

        public TeamModel Winner { get; set; }

        public int RoundNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

**MatchEntryModel**

```
    public class MatchEntryModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public TeamModel CompetingTeam { get; set; }

        public double Score { get; set; }

        public MatchModel ParentMatch { get; set; }
    }
```

**SelectedMatch change**

```cs
private void MatchesListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender,
     SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _viewModel.SelectedMatch = (MatchesListBox.SelectedItem as MatchModel);
}
```

Comment: What do you change `SelectedMatch` or some of its properties? I don't see the change. If you change `SelectedMatch.Entries[0].CompetingTeam.TeamName`, then does `TeamName` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: I change `SelectedMatch`. I've added a code of model which represents a `SelectedMatch` and a code where I change it.

Team name doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` I thought it's not required if the whole model will be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` is wrong, you have set as `sender` the `MatchModel`-object, but the right one is of `TournamentViewerViewModel`, it should report, that its property has changed. Change the first parameter to `this` by `Invoke`:

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedMatch)));
```

Comment: Thanks, that’s helped me.

Comment: You are welcome. :) Next time try to post an [**M**inimal **C**omplete **V**erifiable **E**xample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).